# How to deploy war to remote Tomcat or Jetty server by Maven

Tags: maven, tomcat, deployment, jetty

I am looking a way for making production deployment automate.
Deploy phase in maven is for repository deployment. 
How we can do production deployment when we are using Tomcat or Jetty as remote server?

I am looking something like this: mvn deploy-site then after build maven deploy war to remote server

Comment: Maybe try to make job in Jenkins (http://jenkins-ci.org/)

Comment: I am wondering is this possible with maven?

Comment: for using Jenkins, I should install it on the server or my local machine? the source is on github

Comment: you should install it on server and it can be configured to build the latest version from repo and deploy it to server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven is not intended to do deployment in the sense you are using it. Just use something different: Ant, Shellscript, Jenkins Jobs, Chef, Puppet or something similar.

Apart from that it is possible to do so by using the [cargo-maven-plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) and other plugins.

Comment: Excuse me, where did you get the idea maven is not intended to do deployments in this sense? Of course complex environments use puppet or chef, shellscripts are also being used.. but if ant can do the job, why wouldn't be maven appropriate? (e.g. for smaller projects, or even larger projects with straightforward deployments?)

Comment: Maven is a build tool and *not* a deployment tool. I didn't say you can't do it but it's not the intention of Maven. You can of course go via different plugins. I would suggest to use pom packaging in a separate project and bind the appropriate plugins to the appropriate phases.